# How do I get persistentSize in ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I can't figure out how to get persistentSize in an Artemis ActiveMQ queue using JMS. I didn't find any get method in the Message class. There are different methods for getting message ID, lifetime and others, but I didn’t find any for getting persistentSize
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the ActiveMQ Artemis "persistentSize" value from a JMS `Message` using the JMS API. This property is not part of JMS. It is specific to ActiveMQ Artemis.

That said, you can simply look at the message itself to determine how large it is. For example, if the message was a `TextMessage` then you could use the [`getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html#getText--) method to get the `String` body and then use the `length()` method to see how long it is. If the message was a `BytesMessage` you could just use the [`getBodyLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html#getBodyLength--) method.

If you *really* wanted to get the "persistentSize" and you were using the core JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis then you'd have to cast the JMS `Message` to the ActiveMQ Artemis implementation object `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage` and use the `getCoreMessage` method to get the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage` and then invoke `getPersistentSize()`.

This, of course, is **not recommended** as it would destroy the portability of your application which is one of the main benefits of using an API like JMS in the first place. In short, you could never use this code with any other JMS client implementation or any JMS other broker implementation and since it's considered internal then it is subject to break without notice during an upgrade.

Comment: What do you mean by portability? I won't be able to use this application on ActiveMQ itself or on other resources that use JMS? If I only need ActiveMQ Artemis, will it work for me?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!